# Setting foreignField in virtuals pointing to dynamic refs (refPath)?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using dynamic refs for my `Comment` model, and I want to set a virtual in my `Post` model to populate its comments.

```js
const commentSchema = new Schema({
   body: String,
   parentDoc: {type: String, enum: ['Post', 'Comment'] }
   parentID: {type: Schema.types.ObjectID, refPath: 'parentDoc' }
});

const Comment = model('Comment', commentSchema);

const postSchema = new Schema( {}, {
  virtuals: {
    comments: {
      options: {
        ref: 'Comment',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'parentID'
        // Do I add a matcher here to check parentDoc === 'Post' maybe? 
      }
    } 
  }
})
```

What's the correct way to set up this link? Right now my idea is to add a matcher that checks its `parentDoc` value. Is there a more direct and intentional way?